# I have pip version 19.3.1 but when installing requirements, it says I have version 9.0.3

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install requirements.txt in pycharm, but pip version indicated version 9.0.3 whereas I have 19.3.1. It will not update saying that requirement is already satisfied.

I've tried upgrading it but it says requirement already satisfied

> You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
>
> :\Users\User\Documents\Learn\Python\photography>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
>   Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\user\documents\learn\python\photography\venv\lib\site-packages (19.3.1)

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: If you are on windows, its possible you have two different installations.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have two versions of Python installed? That could be the cause.

Comment: I have version 3.7.4 and 3.8

Comment: Then that is probably the reason why. The best thing you can do then is delete one of the installations; you probably won't need two installations anyway. If for some reason you need to have both installations, then you need to find some way to explicitly reference the installations, which I don't know how to do.

Comment: I deleted on of the installations. It worked. Thanks cricket_007

Comment: Great! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal has photography\venv activated

I'm guessing Pycharm is not using that virtualenv

Regardless, the version of pip shouldn't stop you from using a requirements file