# How to uninstall python version 3.6 and keep version 3.7 OSX

Tags: python, pip

When I run `python3 --version`, I get Python 3.7.9. When I run `python --version`, I get Python 3.6.8. I'd like to remove python 3.6.8 because I am having an issue with Heroku recognizing my pip version when I try to deploy my Flask app to Heroku. When I do `pip -V`, it says that my pip version is version 20.2.2. However, when I try to do `git push heroku master`, it says that I have pip version 9.0.2. I found this post on SO that shows how to fix this issue: [I have pip version 19.3.1 but when installing requirements, it says I have version 9.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58791987/i-have-pip-version-19-3-1-but-when-installing-requirements-it-says-i-have-versi) . However, this answer does not specifically show how to delete the other version of Python (in my case, 3.6.8). I know that there are a lot of posts about how to delete Python versions, but I just wanted to make sure I didn't mess anything up. Also I haven't seen a post about successfully deleting Python 3.6 (to my knowledge). Honestly, I don't really care which version I remove. I most recently installed 3.7.9. I just need one of them gone. Please help!!!

Comment: Generally, you uninstall something in a similar way to how you installed it.  If you used a package manager to do an install, you'd use that same manager to do the uninstall.  It's impossible to know what to do in your case because you don't provide any information about how you installed your Python versions.  Heck, you don't even say what OS you're running.  NOTE: `pip` will not be part of the solution.  `pip` is a part of a Python distribution, and has nothing to do with installing/uninstalling Python itself.

Comment: I downloaded 3.7.9 from this website: https://www.python.org/downloads/. That's it. I have MacOS Catalina. Also I mentioned pip because Heroku failing to recognize my actual pip version is due to the fact that I have multiple versions of Python (according to that post linked in the question). Does this help?

Comment: Would simply deleting that downloaded package do the trick?